# Reference material for the millenium problems and other difficult problems

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, graph-theory, reference-request

None of my University's Professors have made it their lifelong missions to solve a super difficult problem in mathematics (please do not think that I am being judgmental with my post), but I want to pour my life and soul into solving one such problem. You may probably think of me as an overambitious, pretentious college student who's way in over his head (and you might be right, but I do not think you are) - yet I still really wish to do this.

I always read stories about Wiles, Perelman and others and I'm amazed to say the least. However, they seem to either have stumbled upon those problems by chance or were introduced to them in a natural way during their studies which is much different from my experience, with those problems just kinda being there on the internet.
Anyway, here are some problems that I am currently (at the very least tangentially) interested in and what I would love to get by this post (which I hope doesn't break any rules) is to get material that might serve one as a primer and introduction to seriously studying this stuff (be it articles, books, both; be it 10 pages or 1000 or just linking me to pages/blog posts by Professors/researchers doing some of this stuff). I am primarily interested in Abstract Algebra, Graph Theory and Number Theory - maybe this will help with your recommendations.

Without further ado, these are the problems one or two of which I want to dedicate myself to (in no particular order):

- Hodge conjecture,
- Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture,
- Virasoro conjecture,
- Yau's conjecture,
- Erdős–Hajnal conjecture,
- Inverse Galois problem,
- Herzog–Schönheim conjecture,
- Yang–Mills existence and mass gap,
- Grimm's conjecture,
- Goldbach's conjecture and naturally,
- The Riemann Hypothesis

Even if you find my post laughable, please indulge me. Nobody I know personally can help me and just "googling" things will lead me down a rabbit hole that is too wide and deep to dig out of. I only need some in-field guidance, nothing more. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've been working on the Twin Primes conjecture for about twenty years now, and my one suggestion is to take anything you feel is a breakthrough very skeptically.  You probably have a pretty good chance of making significant progress on any one or maybe two of these problems, and your own understanding of them will go up and you will learn a lot, but it's better to be humble about what progress you make.

Comment: And and all of these problems are very well documented online.  I don't think any short response here could usefully add to the volume of material out there.

Comment: @abiessu Apologies if my post gives off a "too confident too proud" vibe - I just want to start and see where I'm taken, instead of kicking myself in the head 30 years from now, saying "back then I should have done X". Thanks for the response!

Comment: @lulu I am aware that they are all well documented online, but I am unsure if there is such a thing as a "best" place to start. (Regardless of whether it's for all of them or individually)

Comment: No worries about your tone here, just a suggestion for when you feel like you want to tell the world about the progress you've made.

Comment: Well, since nobody knows how to solve any of them, it isn't clear what "best" might mean.  Failed approaches might contain germs of good ideas, or they might simply be bad ideas.  Partial results may be interesting or suggestive or they may require so many extra assumptions as to render them incidental special cases.  Not trying to be negative, but your question is like asking for directions to the lost city of El Dorado.  If we knew where it was, we'd be headed there.

Comment: To give a relevant historical example, Hilbert considered the transcendence of $2^{\sqrt 2}$ to be a far more difficult open problem than the Riemann Hypothesis.  A century later, the former is well understood and generalized, while the latter is as open as ever.  Our intuition as to which open problems are ripe for solution just isn't very good.

Comment: *just "googling" things will lead me down a rabbit hole that is too wide deep to dig out of* --- This is like someone wanting to win all 4 grand slam tennis tournaments who says that watching people play tennis to learn the rules and how to hold a racket correctly seems to be leading down a rabbit hole. Get a Ph.D. in math (trivial for anyone capable of solving such problems), publish papers extending various known results and then aim for stronger results (that's like saying "play in some sanctioned tournaments"), then . . .

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Is there anything wrong in asking _which_ tennis matches and players to watch while starting out?

Comment: Well for me it was probably (U.S.) college scholarship male players and most any college-to-professional level female players (for me, back in the mid 1970s to mid 1980s), because the shot-making was more reproducible and (especially in the case of female players) there was less of the serve-and-volley type play whose attempted imitation leads to a lot of unforced errors by someone not already at a reasonably high level of play (i.e. at least at a U.S. nationally ranked junior level), plus it's difficult to pick up style and strategy when watching only serve-and-volley.

Comment: The analogy for math would probably be to first begin absorbing all you can from books widely reputed to be very well written and by masters of the subject --- Spivak's (basic) calculus text, Herstein's "Topics in Algebra", Halmos' "Measure Theory", Hardy and Wright's number theory book, etc. But trying to list all such books would result in an enormous list that would be essentially useless. You should ask a question about such books for a specific topic, and especially of what type of background is needed for the various books.

Comment: Your post is a very nice illustration of "without further ado", indeed. Hey, if you want to solve one of those problems, go ahead and do it.

Comment: Oh well, looks like I'm left to my own devices. If this site is still online in some 15-20 years from now, I'll do my best to remember to update my post to let you know how it went! (Hopefully it'll be a "yay I did it" comment :) 
Thanks to everyone who replied.